# Wordpress Permalink Htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I need help with Permalink in Wordpress 3.7.1.

The website is this: http://estudiomusical.com.br/

When I set at permalink config page: /%postname%/

Pages doesn't load, 404 page appears.

I was developing this website at a windows server ... and the file web.config to fix this issue.

I have now .htaccess with this code inside:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help me?
I need to get the pages with the correct names to work some functions.. for example jQuery UI Tabs assigned with advanced custom fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Once go in `settings->permalink` section and try again.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx